# React. Каким образом я могу разделить логику без создания доп. компонента?

Tags: reactjs

Хук:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export const useFade = () => {
  const [isFade, setIsFade] = useState(false);

  return {
    isFade,
    onMouseDown: () => setIsFade(true),
    onMouseLeave: () => setIsFade(false),
    onMouseUp: () => setIsFade(false)
  };
}
```

Компонент с общим состоянием isFade для цикла:

```
import React from "react";
import { useFade } from '../hooks/useFade';

export const ChangeColorOption = ({ colors }) => {
  const { isFade, ...fadeProps } = useFade();

  return (
    <div
      role="button"
      tabIndex="0"
      className="context-menu-option"
    >
      <div className="context-menu-option-colors">
        {colors.map((color, idx) => (
          <div
            {...fadeProps}
            key={idx} 
            className={
              isFade 
                ? 'context-menu-option-color fade'
                : 'context-menu-option-color'
            }
          >
            <span className={'icon ' + color}></span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Как я могу использовать состояние для каждого элемента в цикле без создания отдельного компонента с этим хуком?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\hooks\use-stores.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { storesContext } from '../contexts/global'

export const useStores = () => React.useContext(storesContext)
```

\contexts\global.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { MyStore } from '../stores/my-store'

export const storesContext = React.createContext({
  myStore: new MyStore()
})
```

\store\my-store.js

```
export class MyStore {
// все данные которые нужны + методы доступа к ним
}
```

Comment: Контекст отличная вещь для хранения общего состояния, которое здесь как как раз не нужно. То есть пропа isFade итак сейчас с общим состоянием. Или здесь играет роль оператор new? Не могу понять как реализовать задачу.

Comment: Идея заключается в том, чтобы вынести всю логику + внутреннее состояние элемента в отдельный класс и все это хранить глобально; new задаст начальные значения; P.S. то что мы храним глобально не так важно, т.к. использует это глобальное-значение только тот компонент который его подключает; И получается что мы используем контекст как раз чтобы отделить всё что касается элемента и перенести в класс

Comment: Сам не использовал классы, только функциональные компоненты. Благодарю!